# Dual Boot Windows 10 login requires booting twice

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot

I have a dual boot of Windows 10 with Ubuntu 17.10. When I log into Ubuntu, everything works fine. Within Windows, everything is working fine as well. However, whenever I log out of Windows, I get a blue screen which says "Step 7 of 7: something something something." Then, when I try to log back into Windows (after logging into Ubuntu), I first get a screen which goes through steps 1 and 2 of 6, then restarts, and if I again select to boot into Windows, then it goes into Windows.

This significantly increases the main drawback of a dual boot, which is the time it takes to switch OS. How do I fix this?

Comment: Excuse the irrelevancy please, but why dual-boot and not virtualization?

Comment: To find out more about that, I suggest you take a look in Event Viewer’s System and Application logs. Do you have the Windows partition mounted in Linux? Did you disable any Windows 10 features that you feel affect your privacy? Is your Windows up to date?

Comment: @TrippKinetics RAM limitations, primarily.

Comment: " "Step 7 of 7: something something something." -- does that mean a pending update is completing? There should be no difference between single OS and dual-boot, comparing *cold* boot time. However, you cannot enable Hibernate in Windows.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Is it possible that a pending update is having trouble completing, and if so how would I resolve that? I've booted into Windows several times and gotten this each time.

Comment: Check Windows Updates.

Comment: Make sure Hibernation and Fast Startup in Windows are disabled.